# i am using node cron for running jobs , i will this run every day including saturday and sunday '00 00 22 * * *'

Tags: node.js, angularjs, coffeescript

- i am using node cron for running jobs , i am confused  will this
  pattern run every day including Saturday and Sunday as well

'00 00 22 * * *'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have an entry too many in your cron expression.

It should be:

```
minute hour dayofmonth month dayofweek
```

Assuming you want to run at 10pm every day:

```
0 22 * * *
```

If you ever need to double check your cron expressions, I recommend using [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/)